# Percentage of proximity between two integers that can be zero

Tags: percentages

I have two numbers, for example $4$ and $5$ and I need to calculate the percentage difference between them, in this case ~$77.8\%$, found by subtracting to $100$ the percentage difference of them:

$$100 - \left(\left(\frac{5-4}{\frac{5+4}{2}}\right) \cdot 100\right)$$

It would generate $$100 - (0.22 \cdot 100) = 100 - 22.2 = 77.8$$

This is fine, but it doesn't work with **zero** values.

If I need to compare $0$ and $5$ (or $5$ and $0$), the result should be $0$, since they are totally different, but $1$ and $0$ would be a greater number, of course.

How can I deal with them?

Comment: Avoiding a division by zero, change the definition and replace the denominator by $(|x|+|y|)/2$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference#Percentage_change.

Comment: You shouldn't be subtracting from $100$.  This would give the percentage difference between two equal numbers as $100\%$, which is not what you want.  The $22.2$ (aside from rounding) is the ratio of the difference to the average value, which is probably what you want.  Comparing any number to $0$ will then give $200\%$ because the difference is twice the average.

Comment: @Ross Ok... The goal is have the percentage more near 100% as the numbers are more equal. For example "5" and "5" = 100%, "1" and "5" = 20%, "4" and "5" = 77% (about?). For this reason I subtract the result to 100, if you have any idea please share :)

Comment: @MichaelHoppe isn't it already (x + y) / 2?

Comment: Not in case that $x=-y$.